# Find points that fall within a radius using Hibernate Spatial

Tags: postgis, hibernate-spatial

I am using hibernate spatial and postgis and i want to find the points that fall within a certain radius. Using this SQL:

```
SELECT name FROM institution WHERE ST_DWithin(geom,ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(36.9881 0)'), 5000)
```

I get the points within 5KM.

Using Hibernate Spatial i am doing

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Institution.class, "i");
Geometry geometry = ....

criteria.add(SpatialRestrictions.distanceWithin("i.geom", geometry, distance));
```

But it does not return distance in Metres. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide geographic data to evaluate distance but you are passing geometry.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20577961/6490042

SRID 4326 geometry is in degrees not meters.

Answer (score 0):

distanceWithin() function take distance in degree which you have to cast to geograph but hibernate Spatial doesn't support so there is another way by which you can achieve this by providing distance in decimal according to your requirement.link is mention below for decimal points.

**LINK** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

[image]